# Generating a Gausian data with dependent error

Tags: normal-distribution, independence

I want to generate a Gaussan simulated data with dependent error through R.
I wrote my code, but I'm not 100% sure that I did it right. Would someone be able to check if I did it correctly?

I assume that data $\mathbf{Z}$ is in $\mathbb{R}^n$, $n > 1$, and it follows Gaussian distribution.
Then, I let $\mathbf{Z} = \mathbf{Y} + \mathbf{\epsilon}$, where $\mathbf{Y}$ is the latent process of interest and $\mathbf{\epsilon}$ is white noise process.
Because I want $\mathbf{Z}$ to follow Gaussian distribution with dependent error, I have $$\mathbf{\epsilon} \sim MVN(\mathbf{0_n},\mathbf{\Sigma})$$,
where $\mathbf{\Sigma}$ is a symmetric matrix with all entries on the main diagonal equal to each other.

Am I generating my simulated data corretly? Thank you!

Comment: Hi: The procedure sounds okay but I would use the term "correlated" errors rather than "dependent" errors just to be slightly more clear. Some might say it doesn't matter but dependent errors usually denotes that the error term is correlated with itself over time. Correlated errors usually denotes that one error is correlated with another error ( like in seemingly unrelated regression ).  In your case, have  errors are correlated with each other.

Comment: @mlofton Thank you for the advice! :)